# flstudio reduce chord length

Tags: fl-studio

i have a sound track created by a my friend .i draw them in a piano roll and it's perfect.but the problem is my created one using flstudio bit slow.how can i increase speed without re drawing all the chords.

This is what i currently have

[image]

and This is what i want

[image]

i tried grouping all and decrease width of cell but then there are spaces between cells.
thanks.hope it's clear

Comment: Increase the tempo?

Comment: @Tetsujin i think yes.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just an tempo increase you want, then assign automation to the bpm knob and then use the graph to change the knob value over time... but the second part of your question about the note lengths sounds like you are talking about quantization: [Google search for quantization fl studio](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=b0N8W5T0M8uotQWwsIm4AQ&q=quantization%20flstudio&oq=quantization%20flstudio&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1j0i13i5i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.10545.19837.0.20658.23.16.7.0.0.0.119.1145.12j4.16.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.23.1161...0j0i22i30k1j0i131i67k1j0i67k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.TaQ6EKPb6i0)